# User update profile and mysql update

Tags: mysql

I will give as example user profile edit page. There are 12 different fields inside form (age, gender, smoking, drinking, ...). All those fields are in single table. When user saves data, mysql update statement is used to set all data, even if only one field has been changed.

```
UPDATE profile SET age=22, smoke=1, drink=1, ...
```

But I am wondering if this is a correct way. Is better way to first check which field was changed and SET data only for this field? To accomplish this, I would put all current values in hidden input. It would look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="oldAge" value="<?php echo $age; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo $age; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="oldGender" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>" />

<?php
//...
if($_POST['oldAge']!=$_POST['age']){
  $updateQuery .= ", age=$_POST['age']";
}
if($_POST['oldGender']!=$_POST['gender']){
  $updateQuery .= ", gender=$_POST['gender']";
}  
//...  
?>
```

In this way fewer data are set and this could make better mysql performance. Does this make any sense or is it just unecessary complicating things?

Comment: You are right, check which field/s was/were changed and set only those field/s to save unnecessary updates.

Comment: this question might be a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459669](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459669)

Comment: Yes you are right, I missed it and I aplogy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do checking with javascript jquery since I already use it to send post data with ajax.

```
var oldValues = $('form').serialize().split("&"); 
var values = '';        
var valChanged = false;
var curValues = '';
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('form').submit(function() {
        curValues = $(this).serialize().split("&");
        for(var i in curValues){          
          valChanged = false;          
          for(var i2 in oldValues){
            if(oldValues[i2].split("=")[0]==curValues[i].split("=")[0] && (oldValues[i2].split("=")[1])!=(curValues[i].split("=")[1])){
              valChanged = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          if(valChanged==true){
            values = values+curValues[i]+"&"; 
          }          

        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: $(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
          data: values,
          success: function(msg){                              
              //saving done
              closeDialog(200);                            
          }           
        });     
        return false;           
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just making the things complicated, what you can rather do is simply keep the field 'age' and echo the old age in it. Once the user changes the value and sends the form, just update the value in data.
To check if its the same as it was earlier apply a javascript validation to the change and alert 'no changes made' if the user submits the form without changing any value.

Hope this helps.